# Am I doing the right amount of volume for biceps?

Tags: training, resistance

I know biceps are small muscle group and they can recover quickly.
I do 5 to 11 sets with different exercises(these sets contain dropsets)
My workout log looks like this:-
Warm up sets:
Set 1:2kg db curl with 10 reps at each hand.rest 1 min or less
Set 2:16kg concentration curl 5 reps at each hand. rest of 2 mins
set 3: same weight and 2 reps at each hand.2 min rest.
set 4:12kg with 8 reps st each hand
And this follows on till 9 kg.
I follow this schedule on 2 days per week or 1.I have not noticed any increase in my arm size. As you can see I try to do both strength and muscle building known as high reps or low reps but wait is it possible for me to do both weights that I can handle and those weight which i can't but for increase strength.
One more question hope you don't mind that I am easily able to do dumbbell curl with weight of 12 kg but I am unable to handle 9kg barbell curl(Do you think that through isolation exercise i have messed up my arm positions?.)

Comment: Start squatting and eat more. Pull ups help with increasing bicep size. Stop doing so many curls.

Comment: wide grip pull ups or close grip chin ups?,i am only able to do like 3 or 2 in the first set so how can i manage to do more?

Comment: Any grip variation will work your biceps, but some more than others. Just start incorporating pull ups into your routine and don't get stuck doing only one kind. Avoid any grip that hurts your shoulders. You can also do cable lat pulldowns - wide grip bar and chin up attachments - as a supplement exercise after doing pull ups.

Comment: My biceps are pretty big and I've never done in a curl in 10 years. Pullups with plates dangling off a chain and bb rows are all I've needed.

Comment: Shoulder width chin ups are very good for biceps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are NOT doing the right amount of volume. You're doing way too much. And too little.

Too much curling, too little of anything else.

If you want to see progress, you need variation in your exercise. If you just curl all day, your body will simply get good at curling. It doesn't even need to build muscle, it will just create new neural patterns to help you do this particular movement.

You need a complete workout program for your entire body. Like @TestWell says, you need to squat and everything.

And I know what you're thinking. "Squatting doesn't do anything for my arms."

Well, you'd be wrong. When you're doing a full-body program, there are synergies between all muscle groups and exercises. Your CNS (Central Nervous System) as well as your bones will be developed, and this is something that will yield results all over. And squatting (as well as all the other exercises) is an integral part of this.

There are plenty of good beginner programs out there. I believe [SL5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/) is among the most popular. You'd do well to start there.

And I promise and guarantee, you'll see more results in 4 months of that, than you would in 1 year of what you're doing right now.